# Selenium - Python - Click Child Element based on Parents Class Name

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am navigating a webpage using selenium and clicking various buttons to perform various tasks. Every button I've clicked so far has some sort of unique identifier that allows me to accurately locate and click that element. However, there is a button that shares all identifiers with other buttons on the same page (i.e. no way to identify this one directly). This button is a descendent (7 generations below) of an element with a unique identifier class.

The page buttons are dynamic so many elements change attributes each time the page is loaded.

I have tried every combination under the rainbow to click this button but have not found any solution.

Here are some of the scenarios I have tried:
1.

```
ele = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='firsttile']//*[@class='md-icon-button md-accent md-button md-ink-ripple md-default-theme']")
ele.click()
```

2.

```
ele = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='firsttile']/*/[@class='md-icon-button md-accent md-button md-ink-ripple md-default-theme']")
ele.click()
```

3.

```
ele = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='firsttile']*/*[@class='md-icon-button md-accent md-button md-ink-ripple md-default-theme']")
ele.click()
```

4.

```
ele = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='firsttile']///////[@class='md-icon-button md-accent md-button md-ink-ripple md-default-theme']")
ele.click()
```

This is the button:

```
<button class="md-icon-button md-accent md-button md-ink-ripple md-default-theme" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="menu_container_338">
```

This is the parent with unique identifier as firsttile

```
<measure-tile measure-info="measure" ng-class="measure.lookup + 'Tile'" class="firsttile">
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated! Nothing on stack or other websites have helped me solve this problem yet. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I have attached the full DOM path here Originally I posted that the class name was 'firsttile' but was de-identifying it in my post. The true class name is 'ontimestartsTile'. [image]

I have attached my most recent attempt here:

```
parent = browser.find_element_by_class_name('firsttile');
    button = parent.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='md-icon-button md-accent md-button md-ink-ripple md-default-theme']")
    button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPathing you use is quite specific. I would try something along the lines of:

```
//*[@class="firsttile"]/div/div/span/div/whatever/[contains(@class,"md-icon-button")]
```

Comment: Thanks @LoflinA, I tried to adjust like you recommended but still not working. Here is what I tried: ```//*[@class="firsttile"]/md-card/md-card-title/md-card-title-text/md-menu/button```

Comment: it looks like /md-card/md-card-title/etc are identifiers like "md-icon-button" what you're looking for are the html tags like span, div, input, h2, etc  like my example. Hope this helps.

Comment: also you can do a ctrl+f in the Elements section when you inspect an element in your browser and try building the xpath in the search box and confirm it highlights the element.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with python but it would be pretty much the same as other languages. Hoping it helps here is c# code for reference

1. If your button has a unique class from subtree starting from your parent node use below code reference

   `IWebElement parent= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("first time"));`
   `var myButton= parent.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='md-icon-button md-accent md-button md-ink-ripple md-default-theme']"));`

Now if you are not sure about the uniqueness of element property which is class in your case then you can use to list out the elements as follows.

```
List<IWebElement> Managers = parent.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='md-icon-button md-accent md-button md-ink-ripple md-default-theme']")).ToList();
```

2. if it has more than 1 element in the list then you should go with absolute XPath.

   **Note**:- if you copy XPath from Firefox it will mostly give you absolute XPath whereas chrome on another side will give relative. sometimes you have to create by yourself if browser doesn't give absolute value.

I hope this workout for yours. if you can share a link or inspect element snapshot showing Full DOM I can help you even better. Thanks :-)

Comment: thanks for the insight but I am still stuck. I have edited my original post to include the full DOM of the parent and child button. I have also included the most recent attempt. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out it out with the appropriate syntax. I first had to define the parent object as a variable, then used that variable in identifying the child button. Here is my solution:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('ontimestartsTile')
element.find_element_by_xpath('.//button[@class="md-icon-button md-accent md-button md-ink-ripple md-default-theme"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be locating the parent via [class attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_class.asp) and then use [descendant axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) to find the button, something like:

```
//measure-tile[@class='firsttile']/descendant::button
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 0):

The best solutions is use the method "find_element_by_css_selector()". It is the most reliable method. One line solution:

`browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.ontimestartsTile button[ngclick="$mdOpenMenu($event)"]').click()`